# How to make python discord bot send an automated dm to myself everyday?

Tags: python, web-scraping, discord, discord.py

I am fairly new to discord bots, and I wanted to know how(if it is even possible) I could send a message to myself through my bot everyday. I am making a web scraper but do not want to run it every single day, I would much rather have the bot dm me with the scraped results instead. Can someone help?

Comment: It might be better if you use something like `IFTTT`

Comment: @Goion what exactly is that?

Comment: https://ifttt.com/

Comment: @Goion Thank you for the suggestion, but I don't think that is a solution for me. Would appreciate if you could tell me how to do this on my discord bot.

Comment: No. You can literally automate the message thing with that bot. Also, you misunderstood SO. This isn't a free coding service or tutorial website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to that would be tasks.

```
@tasks.loop(hours=24) 
async def sendmessage():
    users = [Youridhere]
    for id in users:
        member = await bot.fetch_user(id)
        try:
            member.send("Yourmessagehere")
        except:
            pass #do something if message couldn't be sent
```

Next you have to start the task, you can do that in an event or command. For example:

```
@bot.command()
async def startmess(ctx):
    sendmessage.start()
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('✅')

@bot.command()
async def stopmess(ctx):
    sendmessage.stop()
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('❌')
```

You can read on tasks here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html